# How placement.info control the shape created in controller's action

Tags: orchardcms, wrapper, shapes

The action return a ShapeResult. And the shape was created in that action on the fly. As the Action is a general purpose action, like List, I want to controller the shape show/hide, order and wrapper in Module's placement.info. But it seems that the placement.info could not affect those shape return by ShapeResult.

Has any approach?

Comment: Can you clarify why you think you need placement in that situation? Your controller can return any shape result. As a result, you also control what that shape renders exactly (and what it doesn't show). Placement is only necessary when multiple entities (parts) need to contribute to composing and rendering a page. There's no such requirement with a custom controller.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy, Thanks. I think you are. It has the full control on returned shaperesult. I can do anything I want. By the way, does the shaperesult template follow the Shape Template Naming convention? I return a shape, like "List_UserProductList", and it's template has to locate in the Root views folder. If I use the template path like "List/UserProductList.cshtml", the shape could not find its render template.

Comment: The shape template naming should be the same yes but I'm not sure about folders because that may be more about harvesting the files.

Comment: @hengzhe, regarding the question with template sub paths - i can confirm that this does not work. i had the same issue in the past and i posted a question somewhere regarding this issue. But i cannot find it anymore and subpaths don't work till this day.